# How to make core.yaml effect in a container in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, kubernetes-pod

A peer has been installed in a container.
I wanted to instantiate a chaincode in the container, but it failed because the version of a docker image doesn't exist.
[image]

so, I want to change "fabric-ccenv:latest" to "fabric-ccenv:2.1".
I have tried to modify the core.yaml, but it has no effect.
[image]

I also tried to directly export the varible, it also has no effect.
[image]

my question is how to make the configure effective. maybe my solution is false, but i reffer this link:[Instantiation of Chaincode using Fabric Node SDK gives API error (404): manifest for hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:latest not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62860545/instantiation-of-chaincode-using-fabric-node-sdk-gives-api-error-404-manifest/62862682#62862682)

I really appreciate your warm-hearted help.

Answer (score 1):

In docker-compose.yaml

in "volumes" section of your peer: create bind to location of your edited core.yaml

```
e.g.: - ./channel/config-peers/org1-peer0/:/etc/hyperledger/peer
```

in the "environment" section of your peer: add  FABRIC_CFG_PATH= path to location of edited core.yaml

```
e.g.: FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer
```